# Community isn't on ~15 sites!

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts, community-user

I was looking at the Community user's profile, and I noticed that there was about 15 sites missing in the "accounts" tab. There's a little over 120 sites on SE, and, there's about 15 sites missing from this count. **Why is this happening?**

[image]

Additionally, clicking on view more just shows one account, on Area51:

[image]

Comment: We've been told that the World Will End if we delete Community, so I have a feeling that it must be there on all sites. The most logical explanation I can think of is that for some reason not all of Community's profiles are connected to each other. If we could identify one of the sites that don't appear on the list, we could visit it, search for the Community user, and see what it says.

Comment: My guess is that its accounts list is manually handled, and the team didn't update it for a while.

Comment: @hichris123 Yeah... but it says 106 there, too.

Comment: @hichris123 Good find! The account [still exists](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), though. And the same 106 sites appear there. So as to why they aren't all showing up on the list, I'm not sure, but Community *does* presumably exist on them all, so yay, the world is not Ending. :)

Comment: Community had some of her questions closed on those sites, and decided to ragequit.

Comment: I just glanced back at this screenshot and the mouse cursor confused the hell out of me. I thought Community was playing some mean trick on me at first :/

Comment: For what it's worth, those are the sites that are not listed in [Community Accounts list](http://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts): Software Recommendations, Ebooks, Beer, Stack Overflow em Português, Aviation, Joomla, Mathematics Educators, Expatriates, Earth Science, Arduino, Tor, Amateur Radio, Italian Language, Astronomy, Pets

Comment: @ShadowWizard SR.SE has profile for Community user: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Comment: @gnat I know, that was never the issue here. The bug it that the [all accounts page for Community](http://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) shows only one account, while it got account on all the sites in the network. My guess it some internal change in the database structure causing it to break at some point.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see, thanks! this seems to be already pointed out in [comment above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230431/community-isnt-on-15-sites?noredirect=1#comment757013_230431) "why they aren't all showing up on the list, I'm not sure, but Community does presumably exist on them all..."

Comment: Just btw, I already reported the bug about the network profile [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243539/what-happened-with-community♦s-network-profile)

Answer (score 10):

It's been three years since this question was asked, and I am now proud to say that the [Community User's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) isn't missing 15 sites anymore.

...Because it's now missing all of them.

[image: 0 communities]

Funnily enough, [Community's SE Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts) still lists Area 51 as its only community.

[image: 1 community on the network profile]

Comment: Using link to Community user profile from the iOS app you still see [105 sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZiVy.jpg). Seems some inconsistency with API.

Comment: @alexolut it was 106 when this was first asked... Community left a site?

Comment: @Cai .. or one site was exterminated :)

Comment: That would make more sense...

Comment: I'm sure it's related to Area51 using a different code base than the rest of the sites. Is this a problem, though? What is the purpose of this answer? It seems like more of a comment, it doesn't address or explain the issue and could certainly fit in a comment box.

Comment: The single source of truth for the site list is *[How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359794/how-can-i-get-urls-and-site-names-for-a-cross-site-sede-query/359796#359796)*.