# What are the communities in Meta Stack Exchange's header?

Tags: support, design, meta, favicon

The Meta Stack Exchange site banner includes logos from a variety of different communities on the Stack Exchange network.

The largest communities are easily recognizable ([image: SO Icon] Stack Overflow, [image: Arqade icon] Arqade, [image: SU icon]Super User). However, I'm unfamiliar with some of the smaller sites.

**What Stack Exchange communities are displayed in Meta Stack Exchange's banner?**

[image: Meta's Header Image]

<sub>Related question from Movies & TV: *[Identify movies and TV shows from the image in the top bar](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1525/48480)*</sub>

Comment: You can look at the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) and see all of the sites for yourself.

Comment: @Servy Stack Exchange has [over 120 communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230431/351462). I only see around 40 logos in the banner

Comment: Okay?  What's your point?  There aren't any sites in the logo that aren't in the list, so you'll be able to find all of the site logos from the logo in the list.  It's not like the site list is incomplete.

Comment: Pretty sure those are all the graduated sites of Stack Exchange. Not sure what about sites still in public beta which got their own design though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header shows all sites that had graduated at the time the image was made.  It's not being amended with new graduations.  (For example, Worldbuilding is not present.)  If you compare it to [the list of all sites, sorted by age](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) and skip over the beta sites, you should be able to match them up (and find out when the cut-off was).

The "oldest" sort is by age of the *site*, not by order of *graduation*, so there might be some sites there that aren't in the header.  But it's a good starting point.